# Solution of LPP by graphical method

Tags: linear-programming

[image]

I need to solve the following LPP using graphical method

Min $z=4x_1+x_2$

subject to
$2x_1+x_2 \geq 2$,

$x_1+3x_2 \leq 4$,

$x_2 \leq 4$,

$x_1, x_2 \geq 0$

But I am not finding any common feasible region. Particularly from the figure we see that there is no common area to first two constraints . How to proceed?

Comment: Note that $x_2\le 4$ is not really necessary, since it is already covered by the first two conditions. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have included my attempts as an image file.

Comment: Are you sure that is the right plot? I got something different.

Comment: Oh! really very sorry. It was a blunder